# add values from list to another list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to add values from ListArray `coords` to the ListArray `linhasCoords` but the `linhasCoords` doesn't get all values.

My point is, for each ID, save all the coordinates Lat and Long.

My code: http://pastebin.com/P2k82wQ3

```
public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<LatLong>> load_RoadAxis() {


        HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<LatLong>> linhasCoords = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<LatLong>>();

        ArrayList<LatLong> coords = new ArrayList<LatLong>();

                int idAtual = 0;
                int idAnterior = 1;

        String query = "SELECT y, x, linha2 FROM trechos_pontos WHERE linha2 <5 ORDER BY linha2, path ";
        try {
                Stmt stmt = db.prepare(query);
                while (stmt.step()) {

                        Double x = stmt.column_double(0);
                        Double y = stmt.column_double(1);
                        //Log.d("TRECHOS", "idAtual: " + idAtual + "X: " + x.toString() + "  Y: " + y.toString());
                        idAtual = stmt.column_int(2);

                        Log.d("TRECHOS", "idAtual: " + idAtual + "  idAnterior: " + idAnterior);

                if (idAtual == idAnterior) {

                        coords.add(new LatLong(x,y));
                        Log.d("TRECHOS", " Coords: " + coords);

                } else {

                        linhasCoords.put(idAnterior,coords);

                        idAnterior = idAtual;

                        coords.clear();
                        coords.add(new LatLong(x,y));
                        Log.d("TRECHOS", " LinhasCoords: " + linhasCoords);
                }      
                }
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("TRECHOS", "A consulta dos trechos falhou");
            }

        //Log.d("TRECHOS", linhasCoords.toString());
                return linhasCoords;
        }
```

A part of my logs: http://pastebin.com/pDUat9CL

```
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 1  idAnterior: 1
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5922273767277, longitude=1.44029380540736]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 1  idAnterior: 1
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5922273767277, longitude=1.44029380540736, latitude=43.5922136050099, longitude=1.44047259717341]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 1
D/TRECHOS(21428):  LinhasCoords: {1=[latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446]}


D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817, latitude=43.5926642101564, longitude=1.43523990190003]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817, latitude=43.5926642101564, longitude=1.43523990190003, latitude=43.5922914378148, longitude=1.43956435379756]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817, latitude=43.5926642101564, longitude=1.43523990190003, latitude=43.5922914378148, longitude=1.43956435379756, latitude=43.5923036302806, longitude=1.43941791555995]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817, latitude=43.5926642101564, longitude=1.43523990190003, latitude=43.5922914378148, longitude=1.43956435379756, latitude=43.5923036302806, longitude=1.43941791555995, latitude=43.5923244338855, longitude=1.43916026189481]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817, latitude=43.5926642101564, longitude=1.43523990190003, latitude=43.5922914378148, longitude=1.43956435379756, latitude=43.5923036302806, longitude=1.43941791555995, latitude=43.5923244338855, longitude=1.43916026189481, latitude=43.5923490976508, longitude=1.43888705045567]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817, latitude=43.5926642101564, longitude=1.43523990190003, latitude=43.5922914378148, longitude=1.43956435379756, latitude=43.5923036302806, longitude=1.43941791555995, latitude=43.5923244338855, longitude=1.43916026189481, latitude=43.5923490976508, longitude=1.43888705045567, latitude=43.592377137392, longitude=1.4385645839831]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817, latitude=43.5926642101564, longitude=1.43523990190003, latitude=43.5922914378148, longitude=1.43956435379756, latitude=43.5923036302806, longitude=1.43941791555995, latitude=43.5923244338855, longitude=1.43916026189481, latitude=43.5923490976508, longitude=1.43888705045567, latitude=43.592377137392, longitude=1.4385645839831, latitude=43.5924023567609, longitude=1.43825904413027]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817, latitude=43.5926642101564, longitude=1.43523990190003, latitude=43.5922914378148, longitude=1.43956435379756, latitude=43.5923036302806, longitude=1.43941791555995, latitude=43.5923244338855, longitude=1.43916026189481, latitude=43.5923490976508, longitude=1.43888705045567, latitude=43.592377137392, longitude=1.4385645839831, latitude=43.5924023567609, longitude=1.43825904413027, latitude=43.5924486368068, longitude=1.43771410203014]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817, latitude=43.5926642101564, longitude=1.43523990190003, latitude=43.5922914378148, longitude=1.43956435379756, latitude=43.5923036302806, longitude=1.43941791555995, latitude=43.5923244338855, longitude=1.43916026189481, latitude=43.5923490976508, longitude=1.43888705045567, latitude=43.592377137392, longitude=1.4385645839831, latitude=43.5924023567609, longitude=1.43825904413027, latitude=43.5924486368068, longitude=1.43771410203014, latitude=43.5924671434473, longitude=1.4375098967783]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 2  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5925479521396, longitude=1.4365973553446, latitude=43.5926291677532, longitude=1.43564264638214, latitude=43.5926625330203, longitude=1.43526523586817, latitude=43.5926642101564, longitude=1.43523990190003, latitude=43.5922914378148, longitude=1.43956435379756, latitude=43.5923036302806, longitude=1.43941791555995, latitude=43.5923244338855, longitude=1.43916026189481, latitude=43.5923490976508, longitude=1.43888705045567, latitude=43.592377137392, longitude=1.4385645839831, latitude=43.5924023567609, longitude=1.43825904413027, latitude=43.5924486368068, longitude=1.43771410203014, latitude=43.5924671434473, longitude=1.4375098967783, latitude=43.5925346838359, longitude=1.43673959999082]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 3  idAnterior: 2
D/TRECHOS(21428):  LinhasCoords: {1=[latitude=43.5921680888747, longitude=1.44100065185853], 2=[latitude=43.5921680888747, longitude=1.44100065185853]}

D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 3  idAnterior: 3
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5921680888747, longitude=1.44100065185853, latitude=43.592147899421, longitude=1.4412301885968]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 3  idAnterior: 3
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5921680888747, longitude=1.44100065185853, latitude=43.592147899421, longitude=1.4412301885968, latitude=43.5921435012598, longitude=1.44127947779876]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 3  idAnterior: 3
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5921680888747, longitude=1.44100065185853, latitude=43.592147899421, longitude=1.4412301885968, latitude=43.5921435012598, longitude=1.44127947779876, latitude=43.5921339259824, longitude=1.44139493077248]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 4  idAnterior: 3
D/TRECHOS(21428):  LinhasCoords: {1=[latitude=43.5922136050099, longitude=1.44047259717341], 2=[latitude=43.5922136050099, longitude=1.44047259717341], 3=[latitude=43.5922136050099, longitude=1.44047259717341]}

D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 4  idAnterior: 4
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5922136050099, longitude=1.44047259717341, latitude=43.5922090466017, longitude=1.44051065409724]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 4  idAnterior: 4
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5922136050099, longitude=1.44047259717341, latitude=43.5922090466017, longitude=1.44051065409724, latitude=43.5922038095384, longitude=1.44057260588265]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 4  idAnterior: 4
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5922136050099, longitude=1.44047259717341, latitude=43.5922090466017, longitude=1.44051065409724, latitude=43.5922038095384, longitude=1.44057260588265, latitude=43.592196812945, longitude=1.4406542751152]
D/TRECHOS(21428): idAtual: 4  idAnterior: 4
D/TRECHOS(21428):  Coords: [latitude=43.5922136050099, longitude=1.44047259717341, latitude=43.5922090466017, longitude=1.44051065409724, latitude=43.5922038095384, longitude=1.44057260588265, latitude=43.592196812945, longitude=1.4406542751152, latitude=43.5921951761103, longitude=1.44068241680208]
```

You can see that `linhasCoords` doesn't have all the values and its `generated` before `coords`, and I doesn't know why.

Comment: Please provide the code here without external links.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (idAtual == idAnterior) {



                    coords.add(new LatLong(x,y));

                    Log.d("TRECHOS", " Coords: " + coords);



            } else {



                    linhasCoords.put(idAnterior,coords);



                    idAnterior = idAtual;



                    coords.clear();

                    coords.add(new LatLong(x,y));

                    Log.d("TRECHOS", " LinhasCoords: " + linhasCoords);

            }
```

So if idAtual is equal to idAnterior it wont be added to linhasCoords, only to coords.
Replace it with this:

```
 if (idAtual == idAnterior) {

                    linhasCoords.put(idAnterior,coords);

                    coords.add(new LatLong(x,y));

                    Log.d("TRECHOS", " Coords: " + coords);



            } else {



                    linhasCoords.put(idAnterior,coords);



                    idAnterior = idAtual;



                    coords.clear();

                    coords.add(new LatLong(x,y));

                    Log.d("TRECHOS", " LinhasCoords: " + linhasCoords);

            }
```

Comment: I think that is not the problem. May be you doesn't understand  but when idAtual is equal to idAnterior the coordinates area appended to coords and when i get a different id i add all the previous coordinates with coords to linnhasCoords.